# Setting grayscale for multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to set the scale colors for multiple plots in a document? My data look something like this.

```
#Fake data
var1<-sample(c('A', 'B'), size=100, replace=T)
var2<-sample(c('Yes', 'No'), size=100,replace=T)
var3<-sample(c('Dogs', 'Cats'), size=100, replace=T)
var4<-sample(c('F', 'M'), size=100, replace=T)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)

#PLot 1
ggplot(df, aes(x=var1, 
group=var2))+geom_bar(aes(fill=var2))+scale_fill_grey(start=0.3, end=0.6)

#Plot 2
ggplot(df, aes(x=var3, 
group=var4))+geom_bar(aes(fill=var4))+scale_fill_grey(start=0.3, end=0.6)
```

I looked through the elements available to modify in `theme_grey()` but it doesn't look like we can modify scale values.

Ultimately what I am trying to accomplish is set up a script so that all plots are printed with grayscale scale values for preparing a document for submission. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another parameter to change the colors from which the plot bars are going to be filled

```
ggplot(df, 
          aes(x=var3, group=var4)
)+geom_bar(aes(fill=var4)
)+scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray2","gray20"))
```

You can play with the values. For these, you could look on all the different names from the [R color palette](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjrnOipiMzZAhWptlkKHSxrBWsQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.columbia.edu%2F~tzheng%2Ffiles%2FRcolor.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1XIn-mwZ73RgG8bxh4Lan4) `adjustcolor` in `grDevices` package.

Comment: I think I have miscommunicated. I would like to use one sort of scale_fill command that then determines the grayscales for all other plots that follow.

Comment: No other thoughts?